# Cannot vibrate the device for 3 seconds

Tags: android, android-vibration

I want my application to vibrate for 3 seconds, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. When I click on the button, it does nothing. At first I tried to do it in the main activity but there was the same result.

**Main Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final Button vibrateButton = new Button(this);
    final Intent vibration = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    vibrateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startService(vibration);
        }
    });
}
```

**Service**

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService()
    {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent vibration)
    {
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the permissions in the Manifest.xml? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 import android.os.Vibrator;
 ...
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 3000 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(3000);
```

**Note:**

Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```